# Does mysqli_fetch_assoc return data in order?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysqli_fetch_assoc to push data into a row array.

```
$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$rows[] = $r;
echo "<br>location:".$r["assigned"]."||".$r["amount"]."<br>";
}
```

The order I see in this php file and the order seen when I execute the query on mysql command line is different. The last and second last row are swapped in php.

In mysql query I am using an `order by timestamp` clause.

I've searched into mysql_fetch_assoc but didn't find any similar problems experienced by anyone else.

Comment: The order of data that is returned by PHP is the same order that is given to it by the database.

Comment: Is `timestamp` a column in your table? Maybe you have two rows with the exact same `timestamp`. In that case you can have the rows ordered differently.

Comment: If you want order, look into using the `ORDER BY` clause in SQL.

Comment: the resultset should have same output as using the MySQL command itself. Are you sure that the querystring is not different ?

Comment: yes, timestamp is "receivedTimestamp" which is auto set to when the record is inserted. The rows do have exact same timestamp but when i query in mysql command the output is different and when i do in php, its different. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of data that is returned to PHP is the order that is returned to it by mySQL.

If the timestamps are identical and that's the only `ORDER BY` field, then yes, it is perfectly possible for mySQL to give different orders from the same query.

Why it would provide them in different orders between to identical queries is unknown; perhaps an artifact from caching or something like that? But the ultimate point is that if there is no sort order specified that differentiates records, then the database is free to provide them in any order it likes.

If you really want them in to always come in the same order, even when there are dups, the simple answer is to add your primary key field to the end of the `ORDER BY` clause. (you *do* have a unique primary key field, right? *right??*)

Comment: Can it be some setting in php.ini or apache? I do have a primary key but the requirement does not warrant a sort on that. Have figured out by adding another field.

Comment: @NaveenSharma - fair enough. I was suggesting the primary field as a last resort to force it to always be in the same order. If you've got another field that does the job, that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which data is returned by the database is *undefined* by default. Nobody makes any guarantees about the order of data returned. If you want a specific order, use an `ORDER BY` clause. This is not specific to any one particular way to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using `ORDER BY` to obtain the sorted array in MySQL.

Doing this query on MySQL console, the result was perfect:

```
SELECT * FROM I_data_grab WHERE auid='3' ORDER BY 'tempo'
```

But the SAME query fetched in PHP returned an unsorted array.

I resolved removing '' in "tempo" variable as this:

```
SELECT * FROM I_data_grab WHERE auid='3' ORDER BY tempo
```

instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM I_data_grab WHERE auid='3' ORDER BY 'tempo'
```